# Display Result Not Showing Up

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

Please help! I was trying to build a mini loan eligibility web app using JavaScript, but my problem is that the display result wasn't showing what it seems to show after clicking on the eligibility button.

Below are my HTML and JavaScript Code.

```js
 


let Amount = document.querySelector("#amount").value;
let Duration = document.querySelector("#years").value;
let amt = parseInt(Amount);
let dura = parseInt(Duration);
let Message = document.querySelector("#result");
//const Income =  parseInt(Amount.value);
//const Years  = parseInt(Duration.value);
function eligibility(){
if(amt < parseInt(50000) ){
    Message.textContent = "Please! You're not eligible for the loan";
   // console.log('Try again')
} else if(amt >= parseInt(50000) ) {
    Message.textContent = "Please Fill the form below and apply"
  //  console.log('Please Fill the form below and apply')
}
}
```

```html
<html>
<form action="" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Income"  id="amount" required  />
                        </div>
            
            
            
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Duration" id="years"  required  />

                        </div>
                    </div>


<button type="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  onclick="eligibility()">Check Eligibility</button>
  
                    <div id="result">
                        
                    </div>

                </form>
        
        </html>
```

Comment: You read the values on page load. They do not update after that. simple console.log lines would show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue was you need to declare those input values inside the function your calling on the button click. Or else they will all be set to the the value that they load up as (null)

I changed your some of your code and added comments throughout. Hope this helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

<html>
<form action="" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Income"  id="amount" required  />
                        </div>
            
            
            
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
                            </span>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Duration" id="years"  required  />

                        </div>
                    </div>


<button type="" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"  onclick="eligibility()">Check Eligibility</button>
  
                    <div id="result">
                        
                    </div>

                </form>
        
        </html>
<script type="text/javascript">


//const Income =  parseInt(Amount.value);
//const Years  = parseInt(Duration.value);



function eligibility(){
    //You need the declare these values inside the function (getting them globally will only get the value they are when page loads up)
    let Amount = document.querySelector("#amount").value;
    let Duration = document.querySelector("#years").value;
    let amt = parseInt(Amount);
    let dura = parseInt(Duration);
    let Message = document.querySelector("#result");
    if(amt < 50000){
        Message.innerText = "Please! You're not eligible for the loan";
       // console.log('Try again')
    }
    //Change this else-if to just an else since you are just checking for the exact opposite of your if statement
    else{
        Message.innerText = "Please Fill the form below and apply"
      //  console.log('Please Fill the form below and apply')
    }   
}

//Prevent form from submitted or else page will reload and no message would be shown
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
});

    
</script>
</html>
```